# Execution order after a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, execution

I have a stored procedure that does some inserts into a table. If I have to execute that same stored procedure repeatedly, each of these executions reflect the Inserts in the table after it ends or it could happen that each insert occurs after the end of the stored procedure execution and overlaps with the execution of the second instance of that stored procedure.

I hope I was clear, if not please correct me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever work is done in a Stored Procedure, unless explicitly rolled-back or automatically rolled-back due to an error, will be there when the Stored Procedure exits. Once a Stored Procedure exits, there is no more work that it could be doing.

This means that within a single session, any number of executions of a stored procedure are handled serially -- one after the other, no overlap.

However, across multiple sessions / connections, the work being done in a Stored Procedure certainly can overlap if that same code (Stored Procedure or even ad hoc SQL) is run at the same time across other sessions / connections.